# Android location: get first location

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I need to calculate some stuff when getting the first location (it does not need to be very accurate).

I have a LocationManager and a LocationListener and until now I have a boolean firstTime which is initially true and the first time the onlocationChanged is called I set it to false. But everytime the onlocationChanged method is called (every 5 seconds) I check if firstTime is false.

This solution doesn't really satisfy me, is there a better way to check for first-time events? (This question may be in a larger context, not only GPS Location).

I'll provide some code for better understanding:

```
boolean firstLocation = true;
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (firstLocation == true) {
            sights = getListForLocation(location, GPS_INITIAL_PERIMETER);
            firstLocation = false;
        }
        // do something everytime onLocationChanged is called

    }
};

/**
 * starts the listener for GPS-Positions
 */
public void start() {
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            GPS_UPDATE_TIME, GPS_UPDATE_DISTANCE, locListener);
}
```

As you can see I need to do something only the first time I get a new location.

Answer (score 1):

Init your location with null and check it:

```
if(lastKnownLocation == null)
{
    //first time
}
```

and in on LocationListener do:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    lastKnownLocation = location;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where if(lastKnownLocation == null) is executed? I don't want to execute it more than one time.